# Using C# LINQ to write the function with two dimensional List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write a function with returning a Z*Y matrix(Y>Z), in C++ Syntax for simplicity:

```
double[Z][Y] Function (double[Y] vector){
    for (int i, i<Z, i++){
        for (int j, j<Y, j++){
            double[Z][Y] Tem[i][j] = vector[i]/vector[j];
        }
    }
    return Tem;
}
```

Now I want to translate into `C#` syntax with `linq` instead of `for loop`(how to query the two dimensional `List`) and use two dimensional `List<List<double>>` instead of `matrix`. Furthermore, how to declare the two dimensional `List` with given size say `Z*Y`?

Comment: This is not C++ syntax, as far as I'm up to date with the current appearance of C++ code.

Comment: ``double[,] result = new double[Z,Y]`` is what you are looking for, mayhaps.

Comment: @ grek40 sorry just for simplicity of the double for loop.

Comment: You will get better answers if you post valid code... simple is when others understand it - and someone who can answer your question will probably understand valid code better than your "simple" version, because the semantic of valid code is defined in the standard while the semantic of C++ alike pseudo code is unknown.

Comment: @ BitTickler need I declare the size of return value of function, and how to declare?

Comment: @ grek40 ok, change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
List<List<double>> GetFactors(double[] vector, int limit){
     return vector.Take(limit).Select(i => vector.Select(j => i/j).ToList()).ToList(); 
}
```

Limit the first dimension to the first `Z` (`limit` in this case) elements of `vector`

```
vector.Take(limit)
```

For each of those values select a list of `vector[i] / vector[j]` (`Y` elements in total)

```
.Select(i => vector.Select(j => i/j).ToList()
```

And return all lists as list (list of list of double)

```
.ToList()
```

You might want to add some zero handling to `j => i/j`, e.g.:

```
j => Math.Abs(j) < double.Epsilon ? i/j : 0.0
```

Comment: How about `ToList()` instead of `ToArray()`, so you match the question requirement?